# Matching difficult formatting of table

Tags: tables, spacing, border

I have the following table I'm trying to recreate:
[image]

I'm translating the text to English and trying to obtain a similar form, but I'm having a terrible time managing the wild world of LaTeX tables! Here's what I have, or at least the closest I've gotten, which isn't much.

```
\usepackage{multicol,multirow,tabularx,pbox,makecell}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{||>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X||}
    \hhline{|t:====:t|}
    \multirow{2}{2cm}{\centering\arraybackslash\textsc{RATIO} \newline \footnotesize of the \newline \textsc{\footnotesize radii}.} & 
            \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\centering\arraybackslash}X|}{\textsc{\footnotesize ratio of the thickness of the electric layer on the two spheres,}} & 
                \multirow{2}{2.5cm}{\centering\arraybackslash\textsc{DIFFERENCE \footnotesize between calculation} \footnotesize and \textsc{\footnotesize observation.}} \\
        \hhline{||~~~~||}
         & \footnotesize according to calculation. & \footnotesize according to experiment. & \\
        \hhline{||----||}
        a & b & c & d \\
        a & b & c & d \\
        a & b & c & d \\
    \hhline{|b:====:b|}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Well evidently it's not going so well. I need a thicker border line, better vertical spacing of the headers, and the flourish I'm not too concerned about, but it would be a nice addition. So what packages can provide a relatively easy path towards this format? And how can I get closer to the goal, with vertical spacing and all?

Answer (score 1):

A place to start from with a `NiceTabular` nested inside of a `tcolorbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=white,
                    colframe=black,
                    boxrule=1.5pt,
                    sharp corners,
                    top=0pt,
                    bottom=0pt,
                    right=0pt,
                    left=0pt
                    }
                    
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newlength{\tablewidth}
\setlength{\tablewidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-8.7pt-5\arrayrulewidth}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{mybox}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{4}{C{0.25\tablewidth-2\tabcolsep}}}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=3pt]
     \scshape\footnotesize\Block{2-1}{RATIO \\ \textnormal{of the}\\ radii.} 
    & \scshape\footnotesize\Block{1-2}{ratio of the thickness of the\\ electric layer on the two spheres,} 
    && \scshape\footnotesize\Block{2-1}{DIFFERENCE \\ between \\ calculation  \textnormal{and} \\ observation.} \\
         & \footnotesize according to calculation. & \footnotesize according to experiment. & \\
        a & b & c & d \\
        a & b & c & d \\
        a & b & c & d \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is much better, thanks. Unfortunately, the MWE isn't compiling on my system, because apparently there's a problem with my nicematrix package. I get several errors such as: "LaTeX error: "xparse/unknown-argument-type" Unknown argument type '!' for the command '\environment NiceMatrix'. For immediate help type H <return>." And then  "Environment NiceTabular undefined. \begin{NiceTabular}". I know it's outside the question, but any idea what's going on? My nicematrix is freshly updated as of today, not sure what could be the issue.